# interpreting ～とどちらが上というものでもなく

Tags: parsing

> 王の身辺警護は基本的に親衛隊が行っている。
>
> これは騎士団とどちらが上というものでもなく、単純に役割を分担している。
>
> ただし王の護衛という重要な役目であり、当然ながら構成する騎士は選りすぐりのエリートばかりだ。
>
> The King's personal security is basically done by his elite bodyguards
>
> Whether this is knights.........., the role is simply assigned.
>
> ....important so gotta go with the elite knights

you can sorta infer the soft counterargument against the first sentence in the 2nd sentence before the initial statement is reconfirmed in the 3rd sentence, but i'm not sure how 騎士団とどちらが上というものでもなくworks in this framework.

how do you interpret とどちらが without the second option?

What exactly is 上 in this context?

How wide is the scope of ~, when it comes to ~というものでもなく in this case?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### どちら

With some annotations it should be

> 王の身辺警護は基本的に親衛隊が行っている。
>
> これは騎士団とどちらが上というものでもなく、単純に **（親衛隊と騎士団は）** 役割を分担している。
>
> ただし王の護衛という重要な役目であり、当然ながら **（親衛隊を）** 構成する騎士は選りすぐりのエリートばかりだ。

The first sentence mentions mainly to the King's elite bodyguards (a group of elite knights).

In the second sentence, next to first one, mentions to another group of knights.

`どちら` implies two similar parts in its context, so the parts will be similar 親衛隊 and 騎士団.

So it can be simply

> 親衛隊と騎士団はどちらが上というものでもなく、単純に役割を分担している。

and the translation should be:

> Between elite bodyguards and knights, neither is superior to the other. They simply share jobs.

(borrowed from comment)

### Interpretation of 上

It means `greater`, `higher rank` or `better position` in this context. In Japanese, sometimes a speaker mentions to someone in higher rank with 上. For example,

> 上の人に仕事を頼まれた。(My boss asked me a job.)

### Range of 〜 in 「〜というものでもなく」

It widely varies. In the second sentence, it covers `騎士団とどちらが上`.

Comment: are you meaning to say "between (親衛隊) and 騎士団, neither is superior to the other?"

Comment: "neither is superior" Yes exactly, I've forgot to write that sorry